# How to grab XML section in text file?

Tags: regex, xml, string, powershell

I have a string that has a section that is in XML format. How can I grab that section using PowerShell? Below is what I have tried so far, but it is not working. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
$text = "2015-07-09 16:19:12,900|INFO Execute
2015-07-09 16:19:12,978|INFO Stop
2015-07-09 16:19:12,978|INFO Start

?<config>
  <name>shsjsjsjsl</name>
  <id>0</id>
  <status>Passed</status>
</config>

2015-07-09 16:19:13,461|INFO End"

$xmlData = $text -match "\?<config>(.*?)</config>"
$xmlData
```

Comment: Try `"\?<config>([\S\s]*?)</config>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include the `<config>` tags in your `$xmlData`  variable, because XML documents must have a single root. And since the XML section spans multiple lines you must make your regular expression include newlines as well, e.g. by using the single line modifier (`(?s)`):

```
if ($text -match '(?s)<config>.*?</config>') {
  $xmlData = $matches[0]
}
```

or by matching all whitespace (`\s`) and non-whitespace (`\S`):

```
if ($text -match '<config>[\s\S]*?</config>') {
  $xmlData = $matches[0]
}
```